# Center Image inside LinearLayout with weight

Tags: android, image, user-interface, gravity

Here's an image of my problem:
[image]
The two small images in the Green and Red rectangles are the images I want centered. They should fall directly in the middle of both of thier parent's respectively.

Here's why it's not working (As far as I can tell):
I've set the width of the wrapper to 0 in order to avoid conflicts with the weight set for each wrapper. This lets me divide the screen right down the middle and divide content on either side. Unfourtunately, I think it also means that each image is trying to center itself on the 0dp portion of the wrapper rather than the dynamic width generated by the weight.

Here's the code, see for yourself:

```
public void mergeHotels(Hotel keepHotel, Hotel absorbHotel, ArrayList<Hotel> absorbArray){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    //get the current player and let him choose what to do with stock first
    Player thisPlayer = players[getPlayerIndexByPlayOrder(CURRENT_TURN)];

    //create the dialog for exchanging stocks       
    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme);
    AlertDialog.Builder stockExchangeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
    stockExchangeDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.stock_exchange_dialog_title));

    LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    dialogLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout dialogHeader = new LinearLayout(context);
        dialogHeader.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        dialogHeader.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50, 1.0f));

            View blankSpace = new View(context);
            blankSpace.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2.0f));

            LinearLayout tileOneWrapper = new LinearLayout(context);
            tileOneWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
            tileOneWrapper.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                ImageView tileOne = new ImageView(context);
                String tileOneResourceName = "tile_" + keepHotel.getName().toLowerCase();
                int tileOneResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(tileOneResourceName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                tileOne.setBackgroundResource(tileOneResourceId);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams tileOneParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
                tileOneParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                tileOne.setLayoutParams(tileOneParams);



            tileOneWrapper.addView(tileOne);

            LinearLayout tileTwoWrapper = new LinearLayout(context);
            tileTwoWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
            tileTwoWrapper.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                ImageView tileTwo = new ImageView(context);
                String tileTwoResourceName = "tile_" + absorbHotel.getName().toLowerCase();
                int tileTwoResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(tileTwoResourceName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                tileTwo.setBackgroundResource(tileTwoResourceId);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams tileTwoParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
                tileTwoParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                tileTwo.setLayoutParams(tileTwoParams);

            tileTwoWrapper.addView(tileTwo);

        dialogHeader.addView(blankSpace);
        dialogHeader.addView(tileOneWrapper);
        dialogHeader.addView(tileTwoWrapper);

        LinearLayout dialogBody = new LinearLayout(context);
        dialogBody.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);   

        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            LinearLayout playerStockDetails = new LinearLayout(context);
            playerStockDetails.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                TextView playerName = new TextView(context);
                playerName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

                TextView playerMoney = new TextView(context);
                playerMoney.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

                TextView playerTileOneQuantity = new TextView(context);
                playerTileOneQuantity.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                playerTileOneQuantity.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

                TextView playerTileTwoQuantity = new TextView(context);
                playerTileTwoQuantity.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                playerTileTwoQuantity.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

                playerName.setText(players[i].getName());
                playerMoney.setText(String.valueOf(players[i].getMoney()));
                playerTileOneQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(players[i].getStockQuantityByCode(getHotelCodeByName(keepHotel.getName()))));
                playerTileTwoQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(players[i].getStockQuantityByCode(getHotelCodeByName(absorbHotel.getName()))));

            playerStockDetails.addView(playerName);
            playerStockDetails.addView(playerMoney);
            playerStockDetails.addView(playerTileOneQuantity);
            playerStockDetails.addView(playerTileTwoQuantity);
            playerStockDetails.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

            dialogBody.addView(playerStockDetails);
        }

    dialogLayout.addView(dialogHeader);
    dialogLayout.addView(dialogBody);       

    stockExchangeDialog.setView(dialogLayout);
    stockExchangeDialog.show();
}
```

So how do I get it to center the images based on the dynamic-width (based on weight), rather than the static width I declared in LayoutParams?

Thanks in advance for your help!

JRadTheBad

Comment: @Lokesh, that's actually unrelated. My problem was happening because I was using weight to decide the width of the parent. In order to do that I had to force the static width of the parent to zero and then set the weight. That solution doesn't work. Hariharan's was spot on even though it looked unrelated completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Add this line in your `LinearLayout` `LayoutParams`

```
tileOneWrapper.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

and also

```
tileTwoWrapper.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Comment: I see what you're doing. Because the image is centered on the wrapper wich has a width of 0, centering the wrapper inside of the dynamic width of itself forces the image to the center. Lemme try it.

Comment: Good Call @Hariharan. Sorry for the early dismissal of your answer. At first glance it looked completely unrelated. It's an unusual solution. Essentially, it forces the 0dp Layout view to center in it's own dynamic widht thereby bypassing any need to try to "center" the image itself. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Lokesh He tried for only `tileTwoParams` `ImageView` **Params** not for `LinearLayout`

Comment: @JRadtheBad did you try that you have given center only for `tileTwoParams` `ImageView` **Params** not for `LinearLayout`

Comment: It's working now. I set gravity for LinearLayout and it forced it where I wanted it. Thank You.